# Insert two consecutive single quotes using psycopg

Tags: python, psycopg2

this seems trivial, but I cannot find the correct answer anywhere. I need to insert two single quotes in a field using psycopg. Meaning, the value to be stored inside column is: `''`

No matter what I try, it either ends up escaped `\'\'` (when trying `''''` as input as per Postgres documentation), or with an error.

Any suggestions, how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure you want to insert a literal "''" you don't even need a bound variable, just write the correct SQL (remember that a literal single quote is "quoted" as two of them, i.e., "''"). An example is much easier to understand:

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('''''')")
```

Else, you can assign the two quotes to a variable and let psycopg do the quoting:

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("''",))
```

Note the extra parentheses and comma to make up the tuple, as required by cursor.execute.

Answer (score 0):

Refs [the psycopg2 doc](http://packages.python.org/psycopg2/usage.html#query-parameters)

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("''",))
```

Comment: Use a tuple, not a list. A list may work but they were never officially supported and may go away in the future.

Comment: @fog fixed, thanks. There is indeed no official document that mentions the usage.